# Is this possible with PHP?

Tags: php, dynamic

I have created a website that works with different sessions and every users has his own page at mydomain.com/user . I want to know that is it possible that if one user logs in from his account and clicks on a button, it displays a HTML BOX on the dashboard of the button specfied user?

When the intended user logs in, he should be able to see the box from his account.

I would specify the username on whose dashboard the box should appear in the button.

Say - I have 4 buttons named 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b.

If user clicks on 1b, it should display  a box on the dashobard of user a. if he clicks on b2, it should display a box on the dashbaord or user b and so on.....

Is this possible? It's like Facebook's instant friend request feature. If yes, can you guys plz give some hint.

Thank You

Comment: strange naming conventions :) ... why 1b, 2b, 3b, 4b if they relate to users a, b, c and d. maybe you wanted to say that user b is the one who clicks those buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do something like that, you need a way to store the messages (boxes) you want to show to the users (using a database with messages associated to users is the easiest). The action of the pressed button would add data there.
This action can be done via a simple form with POST method or via an Ajax Query.

Then, you can check if there are new messages for an user when he/she logs in or refreshes his/her dashboard. You just need to check the database, take the message and remove it (or set a boolean "received" to true). This is pure PHP and not instant (only on login or page refresh).
With this technique, you insert the block in the HTML before sending it to the client.

Finally, if you want instant notification, you should prepare a javascript to do queries for new messages regularly. On the server side, you have a PHP script looking in the database and returning the message data.
With this technique, you send the page without the block and you have another request to get the block and then add it to the HTML with javascript.

Some useful links:

- [Short introduction to relational databas](http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/1469521/Introduction-to-Relational-Databases.htm)
- [Introduction to SQL](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SQL.html)
- [PHP PDO tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) (to access DBs with PHP)
- [jQuery AJAX features](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) (to easily do queries with javascript)
- [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) (Wikipedia article on AJAX, to understand better)

Comment: Great answer. Could you please provide me with some links that would further help me. Thanks. I don't want it to be instant. A normal set up would do just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: and sorry for asking a dumb question, but how do you create a database with messages associated to users is the easiest?

Comment: It depends on your application. How are your user registered ? Do you keep the accounts in a database like MySQL or SQLite ? I will update my answer with details and links.

Comment: It means that you use MySQL. You should add a new table (e.g. "messages") where messages will be stored.

Comment: the links are for displaying content in real time. I don't want real; time or without a refresh, juts normally, even with a refresh is fine. can you plz post some sample code.Thanks.

Comment: @playcat...i'll do so...i love his answer.amazingly helpful..waiting for his reply..

Comment: Sample code would not be really useful since it depends on your application. If you provided more info about your database, I could maybe do something. I also added a link to a tutorial on database access with PHP. About the column format, it depends on what you want to send to the user (for simple text, varchar would be fine).

Comment: oh thanks for the link...it was great...well, the database is really simple....I actually wanna create a webapp thing where the names of all users would be displayed and beside the names would be buttons to contact them  which would result in a message in the dashboard (as mentioned earlier).

Comment: Yes but how are the columns in your user table in MySQL ? Do they have an ID ? A username ? You need a unique identifier to link the message to an user.

Comment: I can see that you are not really familiar with databases, so I added some links about databases and SQL. The theory is also important to understand what you do.

Comment: Amazing links. Yep, the users have unique ID's that is stored in the database.

Comment: So you can easily do a second table with the columns : sender_id (ref to the user pressing the button), receiver_id (ref to the user who will receive the message), text (the text of the message). Then you can show something like "You received a message from user X !" and the text. Now I will leave (midnight in Japan) so if you have more questions related to databases, javascript etc. open new questions. But first, try to find answers by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Pure PHP, not really.  This sort of thing is where you'll need JavaScript.  When user a clicks on b2, they'll make a background request to the server, which records that there's a message waiting for user b.  Then you'll need a periodic request to go out from user b's browser that checks to see if there are new messages available.  If so, display the box to the user.

Comment: +0 You can do that with PHP alone and only need JavaScript for that if you want that to happen without the user's having to reload their pages. But since the user asked for FB, the answer is likely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I think that he didn't deserve a downvote, as he asked for "like Facebook's instant friend request". There could be precisions though.

Comment: It seemed obvious to me that the OP didn't want to reload the pages on either end (It's not really "instant" if there's a reload involved)".  Also, I deliberately left out specifics since I don't know what the OP's familiarity with JavaScript is.  Besides, if I were given my choice, I'd provide a GWT solution, and that's really only applicable to a smaller audience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do so.

You could create, for example, a table that would serve as a 'buffer' for that kind of messages. 
Dashboard or any page where user is logged in could have a little ajax script that would check that table from time to time, and deliver messages if they exist for the logged in user.